# How to connect to NodeJS server(No Express) with nativescript code.("status code: Unknown Error")

Tags: android, nativescript

I have a nativescript shared code connecting to a NodeJS API, which has another origin, I have already set the CORS Policy, and it works with the web side, but i get the error on nativescript.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
ERROR {
  "headers": {
   "normalizedNames": {},
   "lazyUpdate": null,
   "headers": {}
   },
  "status": 0,
  "statusText": "Unknown Error",
  "url": "http://localhost:4000/api/users",
  "ok": false,
  "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
  "message": "Http failure response for http://localhost:4000/api/users: 0 
 Unknown Error",
  "error": {
    "originalStack": "Error: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4000\n    at new ZoneAwareError (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/vendor.js:82629:33)\n    at onRequestComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/vendor.js:101918:34)\n    at Object.onComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/vendor.js:101910:13)",
"zoneAwareStack": "Error: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4000\n    at onRequestComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/vendor.js:101918:34) [<root>]\n    at Object.onComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/vendor.js:101910:13) [<root>]"
```

}
}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must use your local IP instead of `localhost` as the IP of your Emulator / Device will be different.

Answer (score -1):

seems issue with connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:4000\, check the IP, if you are not accessing from the same machine use machine ip rather than local host.